# OpenURL with objectforkey

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cell

I am trying to open a URL from a json file using a UIButton inside a table cell. The problem is the app crashes when the button is pressed which gives me an error that says

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x786c2310'

Here is the code used. The `objectforkey:@"URL"` links to the json file with the string of "http://www.facebook.com".

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ItemCell";
    DCItemCell *cell = (DCItemCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // If we don’t get returned a reusable cell we allocate and initialize one with a custom frame that positions it at the very top left corner of its container and makes it the same width and height as our cell.
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[DCItemCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kCellWidth, kCellHeight)];
    }

    NSDictionary *currentItem = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.thumbnailbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.thumbnail.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[currentItem objectForKey:@"ImageName"]];

    return cell;
}


-(void) btnAction:(id) sender 
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[sender objectForKey:@"URL"]]];
}
```

Comment: You may need to use a subclass of UIButton, in which you set the url of where should it go to the button. 
Because the action event UIControlEventTouchUpInside puts the UIButton tan triggered the action as a sender. if it's a regular UIButton it wont even have the objectForKeyMethod implemented.

Answer (score 1):

The `sender` in

```
-(void) btnAction:(id) sender {
```

is your thumbnailButton, not the JSON file itself. You can

A) store the URL in a property of the `DCItemCell` itself, and implement the target method of the button in that class as well.

B) set the cell.thumbnailButton.tag property of the button to `indexPath.row`, so that you know which row was being clicked.

Comment: I'm at a loss. I know it's probably something simple that would take two minutes. Would you mind looking the code over for me and helping me out?

Comment: In the first method, add: cell.thumbnailButton.tag = indexPath.row; replace the 2nd method with [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[[self.items objectAtIndex:((UIButton *)sender).tag] objectForKey:@"URL"]]; You should probably also call the addTarget: method inside the if (cell == nil) block to avoid duplication issues when the cell is reused. (Apologies for the lack for formatting - sent from my iPhone)

Answer (score 0):

The argument to the `btnAction:` method as the `sender` will the be `UIButton` from the cell. You are attempting to access a property using `objectForKey:` by sending that message to the `UIButton`, which does not implement this method! That is what is causing the crash.

There are several alternatives here. One good idea is to implement the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method of `UITableView`, and in there grab your model object, which should contain the URL.